# The URI you submitted has disallowed characters in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CI_VERSION 3.0.0 and PHP Version 7.1.2. The site works fine on the server but when it is running on localhost it shows error. 
**The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.**
I try both the solution

1. [The URI you submitted has disallowed characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348491/the-uri-you-submitted-has-disallowed-characters)
2. [Codeigniter Redirect -- The URI you submitted has disallowed characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297433/codeigniter-redirect-the-uri-you-submitted-has-disallowed-characters)

After doing changes it shows 404 error.

Comment: What is the URI causing the error?

Comment: @FMashiro, Sorry I don't get you about URI.

Comment: You've submitted a URI, that string of characters that you submitted is causing an error, I would like to know what the string is so that we can check what the disallowed characters are

Comment: http://localhost:81/fei-edusoul/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug

Comment: You tried $config['permitted_uri_chars']  = '';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;?

Comment: @Danny it is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter Redirect -- The URI you submitted has disallowed characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297433/codeigniter-redirect-the-uri-you-submitted-has-disallowed-characters)

Comment: @Danny the comments above `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` state: `Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.`